# problems in handling huge amount of status and comment

Tags: mysql, sql, database, social-networking

Hi I am a newbie in web development. I am trying to develop a social networking site. At database design level I feel like I have some problems. Here are my problems.

I have a status table where attributes are:

- status_id (auto_increment)
- user_id
- status

My plan is when my home page load it will look for my friends from relation table (I have a relation table) and with the user_id from relation table it loads status(ordered by newest) from status table.
Is this a good plan?  I am thinking about it because this table can contain millions of rows (if I am lucky, but I need  the most efficient way) and if one user has 200 or 300 friend querying will it become slow?  Is it necessary to keep very old status in the table? Please give me some advice. This table will have frequent inserts, so indexing may not be a good idea, what you think?
I have also comment table where the attributes are:

- user_id
- friend_id(comment on whose status)
- status_id(comment on which status)
- comment

Here in no primary key. For this table question is same.
I am using MySQL database and MyISAM as database engine.  What about InnoDB?  Which engine will best for social networking?
Please advise, thanks in advance.

Comment: How big do you expect this site to get? Is this a homework assignment/self-learning exercise? The big social networks use NoSQL databases because of performance.

Comment: 1)Way too many questions. 2)Your comment table does not need friend_id, and should probably have a comment_id as primary key

Comment: i want the best way to do this with rdms

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store historical statuses?  If not, just make it an `NVARCHAR` field in the `Users` table.  If you do want to know what Bill's status was on July 3rd, 2011, you'll need the date.  I'm more familiar with Microsoft SQL, something like this should do it:

```
CREATE TABLE Statuses
(
UserID  INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Users (UserID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
EffectiveDate   DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
PRIMARY KEY (UserID, EffectiveDate DESC),
Status  NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```

*IF* that ends up performing inadequately some day, you could also store `CurrentStatus` in the `Users` table, or use a materialized view with just the most recent status for each user.